# How to Overlay 2 Audio clips and Have them play at the same time with Batch scripting

Tags: audio, batch-file, overlay

i'm working on a Batch Version of COD:Black ops 2 and i have only One problem. when i want 2 Audio clips to be played at the same time, it plays one audio clip at a time. for example, i every time the player shoots, it gives out a sound effect. and if the bullet hits a zombie, it gives out another sound effect. both of theses sound effects can be played at the same time. or at least there supposed to. but it's not working. im not using Windows Media Player as my Default media player. here is my code:

```
:shoot
set f%bullet%=Û
if %times% == 0 goto shot_sound
set /a times=%times% + 1

if %face% == 1 set /a bullet=%bullet% - 20
if %face% == 2 set /a bullet=%bullet% + 20
if %face% == 3 set /a bullet=%bullet% - 1
if %face% == 4 set /a bullet=%bullet% + 1
if %bullet% == %p2% goto hit2
if %bullet% == %p3% goto hit3
if %bullet% == %p4% goto hit4
if %bullet% == %p5% goto hit5
if %bullet% == %p6% goto hit6
if %bullet% == %p7% goto hit7
goto play

:shot_sound
set /a times=%times% + 1
if %n1% == gay_pistol start /min c:\Users\%username%\Desktop\zombies\pistol.mp3
if %n1% == Executioner start /min c:\Users\%username%\Desktop\zombies\Executioner.ogg
goto play




:hit2
start /min c:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\zombies\zombie01.wma
if %hp2% leq 0 goto kill1
if %knife% == %p2% set /a hp2=%hp2% - %knife_power%
if %bullet% == %p2% set /a hp2=%hp2% - %power%
goto play
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test if this works because I don't have any music on my computer but I believe typing:

`call pistol.mp3`

call Executioner.ogg

Will work, Hope it helped!